# Reset button is not closing for Table Filter of antd 4.18.5

Tags: reactjs, antd

We are using antd(4.18.5) table filter. when clicking on the reset button, it will reset the dropdown but that dropdown is not closing. I need to close that dropdown when clicking the reset button. Actually when i click on outside of that dropdown, the dropdown is closing and the original table will display by api call. So i need to close that dropdown and original table should display when clicking on reset button. But i am not able to find the function call when clicking on the reset button. I have tried to close that dropdown by giving style.

```
if(document.getElementsByClassName('ant-table-filter-dropdown-btns')[0] && 
   document.getElementsByClassName('ant-btn-sm')[0]){
    document.getElementsByClassName('ant-btn-sm')[0].addEventListener('click',()=>{
      document.getElementsByClassName('ant-dropdown')[0].style.display='none';
    })
}
```

but that also not working. [image]
Anyone can help me on this? Thanks

Comment: By default, the filter menu does not close on reset, to change this you can use the ```filterDropdown``` props.

Answer (score 0):

I was also looking for the same thing. But i figured it out.
In table, we have `locale` prop having the following keys:

***Interface copied from antd Typescript declaration.***

```
export interface TableLocale {
    filterTitle?: string;
    filterConfirm?: React.ReactNode;
    filterReset?: React.ReactNode;
    filterEmptyText?: React.ReactNode;
    filterCheckall?: React.ReactNode;
    filterSearchPlaceholder?: string;
    emptyText?: React.ReactNode | (() => React.ReactNode);
    selectAll?: React.ReactNode;
    selectNone?: React.ReactNode;
    selectInvert?: React.ReactNode;
    selectionAll?: React.ReactNode;
    sortTitle?: string;
    expand?: string;
    collapse?: string;
    triggerDesc?: string;
    triggerAsc?: string;
    cancelSort?: string;
}
```

You can pass a ReactNode in `filterReset` and when we click on that node or `Reset`, you can close the dropdown by adding the `ant-dropdown-hidden` class or by making the filter dropdown visible or hide using `filterDropdownVisible` & `onFilterDropdownVisibleChange`.

```
locale={{
    filterReset: (
        <span
            onClick={() => {
                document.querySelector('.ant-dropdown')!.classList.add('ant-dropdown-hidden');
            }}
        >
            Reset
        </span>
    )
}}
```

We can use `filterDropdown` prop but with this prop, you need to implement everything from scratch (Handling checkbox, displaying all values, buttons etc). I had tried everything but if anyone finds there's any other option to solve this issue, can provide the solution

Answer (score 0):

I found a better solution based in Muhammad's answer.
As he mentioned, in the tables you can find the `locale` prop, which includes the `filterReset` key. This key receives a `React.ReactNode` element, so you need a state to store if the filter dropdown is open or closed and you update it via this element.

```
  const [isFilterDropdownVisible, setIsFilterDropdownVisible] = useState<boolean>(false);

  const filterreset = (
    <span onClick={() => setIsFilterDropdownVisible(false)}>
      Reset
    </span>
  );
  const tableLocale: TableLocale = {
    filterReset: filterreset,
  }

  return (
    <Table
      columns={columns}
      dataSource={dataSource}
      locale={tableLocale}
    />
  );
```

But with this you still won't control if the dropdown is visible or not, for that you have to access the `columns` prop of the table and do some modifications.
The `columns` prop includes the key `filterDropdownVisible`, which indicates if the dropdown filter is visible or not, and the key `filterIcon`, which allows you to handle the behaviour of the filter icon.
So you set `filterDropdownVisible` to the created state and with this the dropdown will be shown or hidden depending on the value of the state. Finally, you use the `filterIcon` to also open or close the dropdown when you click it.

```
  const columns: ColumnsType<SomeType> = [
    {
      title: 'Subject',
      dataIndex: 'subject',
      filters: subjectColumnFilter,
      onFilter: (value, record) => record.subject.startsWith(subject),
      filterIcon: (filtered: boolean) => (
        <FilterFilled onClick={() => setIsFilterDropdownVisible(!isFilterDropdownVisible)} style={{ color: filtered ? '#1677ff' : undefined }} />
      ),
      filterDropdownVisible: isFilterDropdownVisible
    }
  ];
```

In short, you need:

- a state to save the dropdown visibility
- access to the **reset** button, inside the dropdown, to close the dropdown
- access to the **filter icon**, to open/close the dropdown
- access to the `columns` prop that defines the dropdown visibility

I hope this helps